# Cart doesn't update after changing quantity

Tags: php, ajax, post, cart

I am making a cart system using PHP and AJAX. Everything works pretty fine, except for the updating part. When the user clicks outside of the number form, the subtotal will update automatically. I used AJAX for this, but doesn't work. I tested this with the search, everything was fine.

**AJAX function:**

```
function initXML() { //Adaptation for old browsers
    var _xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        _xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        _xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return _xmlhttp;
}
function ajaxFormValidate(_config) {
    /*Structure
        type: 'GET' or 'POST',
        url: 'request URL' Default: location.href,
        method: true or false (optional). False for non-async, true for async,
        sendItem: file or data to be sent,
        success: a callback function when the request is complete
        error: a fallback function when the request is failed
    */
    if (!_config.type) {
        _config.type = 'POST'; //Automatically set type to POST if no type property is declared
    }
    if (!_config.url) {
        _config.url = location.href; //Automatically set url to self if no url property is declared
    }
    if (!_config.method) {
        _config.method = true; //Automatically set method to true if no method property is declared
    }
    var _xmlHttp = initXML(); //Declare request variable
    _xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (_xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && _xmlHttp.status === 200) {
            if (_config.success) {
                _config.success(_xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (_config.error) {
                _config.error(_xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    }; //Check readyState and status to handle the request properly
    //Handle the items sent
    var _Itemstring = [], _sendItem = _config.sendItem;
    if (typeof _sendItem === "string") {
        var _arrTmp = String.prototype.split.call(_sendItem, '&');
        for (var i = 0; i < _arrTmp.length; i ++) {
            var _tmpData = _arrTmp[i].split('=');
            _Itemstring.push(encodeURIComponent(_tmpData[0]) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(_tmpData[1]));
        }
    }
    else if (typeof _sendItem === "object" && !(_sendItem instanceof String || (FormData && _sendItem instanceof FormData))) {
        for (var k in _sendItem) {
            var _tmpData = _sendItem[k];
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(_tmpData) === "[object Array]") {
                for (var j = 0; j < _tmpData.length; j ++) {
                    _Itemstring.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + '[]=' + encodeURIComponent(_tmpData[j]));
                }
            }
            else {
                _Itemstring.push(encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(_tmpData));
            }
        }
    }
    _Itemstring = _Itemstring.join('&');
    if (_config.type === 'GET') {
        _xmlHttp.open('GET', _config.url + "?" + _Itemstring, _config.method);
        _xmlHttp.send();
    }
    else if (_config.type === 'POST') {
        _xmlHttp.open('POST', _config.url, _config.method);
        _xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        _xmlHttp.send(_Itemstring);
    }
}
```

**AJAX called inside a JS file handling the changes in the inputs**

```
// JavaScript Document
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var _ranum = document.getElementsByClassName('ranum');
    for (var i = 0; i < _ranum.length; i ++) {
        _ranum[i].addEventListener('blur', function(){ //Check click outside
            var _this = this;
            ajaxFormValidate({
                type:'POST', 
                sendItem: {
                    u: _this.value, //Send the value after the change
                    id: _this.id, //Send the product id
                },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log('SUCCESS');
                }
            });
        }, false);
    }
}, false);
```

**Handling the changes in PHP file**

```
var_dump($_POST['u']);    
if (isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['u'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['u'])) {
            $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
            $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['u']);
            if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])) {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $u;
            }
        }
    }
```

I see the it logged out 'SUCCESS' in the console, however, when I use `var_dump($_POST['u'])` it doesn't work. Also, it updates the subtotal only if I reload the page.
What did I do wrong? I pretty sure my AJAX function is correct, and JS logged out 'SUCCESS', so what's the problem? Thanks very much

Comment: First of all take a look at the request details being sent to server, it can be seen into "Network" tab into browser's developer tools. Check that request is being sent at all, that its parameters matches your expectations and observe result being sent from server. Maybe it will give you an idea about what is going wrong. Code itself doesn't seem to have obvious problems despite of its style.

Comment: @Flying let me have a look

Comment: @Flying, yeah, it logged out my desired params

Comment: @Flying, I have just realized that the page received the params from AJAX, but would only apply and change the content when the page reloads. I think the problem is I put the PHP handling code before I call AJAX (JS file), so the code executed before any request can be sent